# Is it possible to have a [OneTimeSetup] for ALL tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm using NUnit to run some Selenium tests and I've got a minor issue I want to see if I can get corrected. What's happening is that the *[OneTimeSetUp]* and *[OneTimeTearDown]* is running after each fixture finishes. What I want is to run [OneTimeSetUp] once when the tests are started, and the teardown to run once ALL fixtures have finished.

**TestBaseClass.cs**

```
public class TestBaseClass
{

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
         // Login
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }
}
```

**NavigationTests**

```
[TestFixture]
public class NavigationTests : TestBaseClass
{
    // Tests
}
```

**MainPageTests**

```
[TestFixture]
public class MainPageTests : TestBaseClass
{
    // Tests
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

OneTimeSetUpAttribute has two uses.

In the first, it marks a method in a test fixture that is run once before any other tests in that fixture. That's how you are using it, by inheriting from a base class. The OneTimeSetUp appears, thanks to inheritance, in **each** of your derived fixtures but it is still run multiple times, once for each fixture.

The second use is in a **SetUpFixture**. If you create a SetUpFixture in a particular namespace, it's OneTimeSetUp method will run **once**, before any other tests in that namespace. If you create the SetUpFixture outside of any namespace, then its OneTimeSetUp will run **once** before any tests in the assembly.

UPDATE: Someone suggested that the last sentence should say "outside of any namespace that contains a TestFixture." That would actually be incorrect. The SetUpFixture **must** be outside of any namespace to function at the assembly level. If there is a top-level namespace, which contains **all** test code, then you may also place a SetUpFixture there, with approximately the same effect. But if it's in a namespace with **no** tests under it, then it will never be run.

For more info about SetUpFixture, see the [docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a static boolean variable acting as flag in the BaseTestClass and in the onetimesetup just check it's value e.g.

```
private static bool FirstInitializationFlag = true;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void PrepareTestsStart()
{
    if (FirstInitializationFlag)
    {
        FirstInitializationFlag = false;
        
        // Do actions before all test classes to run
    }
}
```

Of course it will be good to place a comment why you are doing that ;)