# Implementing an ICollectionFixture-like shared context in NUnit tests

Tags: nunit

I'm using NUnit for our unit tests, but I'd like to implement something that sounds similar to xUnit's [ICollectionFixture](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture) feature.

Specifically I'm thinking this would be useful for database integration tests so I can create a new database, run all the tests against that database from multiple test classes, and the drop the database at the end of the test run.

I know I can do this per test class using the `OneTimeSetUp`/`OneTimeTearDown` attributes, but
in this case I'd like to just create the database once for a whole test run.

I could do it for [all tests in a namespace using the `SetUpFixture` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213167/is-it-possible-to-have-a-onetimesetup-for-all-tests), but I have test classes in this namespace that don't need a database, so it would be annoying to have to wait for a database to be created just to run a non-database test.

I'm wondering whether a mix of OnetimeSetUp/SetUpFixture and a singleton would work, or whether NUnit's [custom attributes](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/extending-nunit/Custom-Attributes.html) could help, or if there's another way to solve this?

Comment: I know of no way to do this without modifying NUnit itself fairly significantly. There are various hooks to do most of what you need but the missing piece is knowing when a particular test is the __last__ one using the fixture.

Comment: @Charlie yeah, that was something I was wondering about too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create parent abstract test class with `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown`.
Then this shared resource will be only used in the subclasses of the parent test class.

More information in the NUnit docs: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimesetup.html#inheritance.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTests
{

    // shared resources initialized only once
    protected TestKit _amqpTestKit;
    protected HttpClient _httpClient;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void InitApp()
    {
        var endpoint = Endpoint.Create(
            host: "localhost",
            port: 5672,
            "test",
            "test",
            Scheme.Amqp
        );
        _amqpTestKit = new TestKit(endpoint);

        // setup the application
        var application = new ApplicationFactory();

        // trigger the app to start
        _httpClient = application.CreateClient();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach with a parent abstract class may not be ideal as its `OneTimeSetUp` method will be called for each child class. If you want your `OneTimeSetUp`/`OneTimeTearDown` to be called exactly once per test run then you should use `SetUpFixture`.

NUnit [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setupfixture.html) says:

> - A `SetUpFixture` outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.
> - A `SetUpFixture` in a namespace will apply tests to that exact namespace only, and not to any namespaces below it.

Further implementation depends on your needs and test project structure. If all your necessary tests are in one namespace make sure you put the `SetUpFixture` class in the same namespace too.

Let's consider a more complicated case when your tests are spread out between different namespaces. In that situation, you need to make the `SetUpFixture` class to be used for the entire assembly. To achieve that make sure no test classes exist in the same namespace where `SetUpFixture` is.

Example of file structure:

```
/TestsA
   TestA.cs
/TestsB
   TestB.cs
TestsContext.cs
```

TestsContext.cs:

```cs
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestsContext
{
    public static IDatabase Database { get; private set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {        
        // Initialize Database here
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
       // Destroy your database here
    }
}
```

And then in one of your test classes:

```cs
public class TestA
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var db = TestsContext.Database; 
    }
}
```

Or if you're not a fan of dealing with static properties you can create a base class:

```cs
public abstract class BaseTests
{
    protected IDatabase Database { get; private set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        Database = TestsContext.Database;
    }
}
```

And then inherit your test class:

```cs
public class TestA: BaseTests 
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var db = Database; 
    }
}
```