# OneTimeSetUp runs multiple times in NUnit

Tags: nunit

The NUnit docs describe how to use SetUpFixture so a chunk of code will execute only once. I'm failing to get this working.

I have read [Is it possible to have a [OneTimeSetup] for ALL tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213167/is-it-possible-to-have-a-onetimesetup-for-all-tests) and https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setupfixture.html

I have the following structure for my tests

The actual tests (note the inheritence)

```
namespace net.UiTests 
{    
    [TestFixture]
    [NonParallelizable]
    internal class SanityTests : TestBase
    {    
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TestCleanUp()
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        [Test]    
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And the base class, which is where the `SetUpFixture` lives

```
namespace net.UiTests
{
    [NonParallelizable]
    [SetUpFixture]
    internal class TestBase
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void AssemblyInit()
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public static void AssemblyCleanup()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure why the `AssemblyInit()` method executes multiple times. The stack trace gives me no clues other than `[External Code]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made your base class a `SetUpFixture`, which is causing the problem.

The `SetUpFixture` runs once before and once after all the fixtures in your `UiTests` namespace.

But due to inheritance, each `TestFixture` now "contains" a `OneTimeSetUp` and a `OneTimeTearDown` method. Those methods, when found in a `TestFixture`, are supposed to run once *per fixture class* and that's what they do.

To solve the problem, you have to stop using the `SetUpFixture` as a base class.

Comment: Hi - thank you for explaining this so clearly, I understand what I need to do..